# Как выставить navbar-nav по центру в бутстрапе?

Tags: html, bootstrap

В общем сделал такую шапку:

[image: Шапка]

Пытался выставить navbar-nav по центру с помощью justify-content-center но ставит как-то криво.

Вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ремонт Телефонов - ZipPhone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ZipPhone - Ремонт телефонов</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Главная</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">О компании</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Цены</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Отзывы</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Адреса</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Как правильно выставить navbar-nav по центру?

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны применить `navbar-collapse` стиль `w-100` (`width: 100%;`) и уже применить `justify-content-center` именно ему.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ремонт Телефонов - ZipPhone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ZipPhone - Ремонт телефонов</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Главная</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">О компании</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Цены</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Отзывы</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Адреса</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А ещё задать "container-fluid" псевдо-класс ":after" с идентичной шириной логотипа, что бы "collapse" был между двумя равными элементами.